# How to preserve referrer (Referer HTTP header) across subdomains?

Tags: cross-domain, referrer, referrer-policy

I have a website running on `www.example.com` that makes GET requests to `api.example.com` to process a form. When I examine web server logs for `api.example.com` I see that requests from Safari get the full referer (e.g., [www.example.com/page-where-request-originated](http://www.example.com/page-where-request-originated)). But requests from Chrome only get a partial referer ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)).

I need the ability to track the full referring page when the request hits `api.example.com`. Reviewing the [documentation for Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) it seems my only option is to set it to `unsafe-url`. But that seems overkill because I only want the referrer to be sent for subdomains of `example.com`. Is that possible?

Comment: quite late to the party, I'm facing the same problem. using strict-origin as suggested in jahiler answer seems not working. Everything I tried with referer-policy is too strict (not sending full referrer url to subdomain) or too large (sending full referrer also ouside the main domain)
Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can find is `strict-origin` : `Send the origin as referrer, but only when the request is no downgrade from https to http`.

see: https://wiki.crashtest-security.com/enable-security-headers

Everything else will either omit the referrer completely or send the origin URL without any URL parameters.